# Arcpy - Selecting Attribute and adding attributes to a feature class

Tags: selection, populate, arcpy

I have a .gdb and 1 feature class called **waterlevelDifference**. There are two columns called **Label** (text field) and **Difference** (double field). The **Difference** column contains numbers while the Label column is empty and waiting to be populated.

What I want to do, is select attributes from  **Difference** (eg  Difference > 0.30) and then populate the **Label** (eg Label = "Greater than 0.30") based on the selection. Initially I was going to use **arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management** (to select attributes) and then use **arcpy.CalculateField_management** (to populate), but you can't use **arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management** on a feature class.

My question is, what are the other ways I can select and populate attributes using a feature class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using a python code block in the field calculator in ArcMap, however if you're wanting to do it in a script, I would create an arcpy.UpdateCursor(), then calculate the value for Label and add it row by row.

```
feature_class = r"path\to\class"
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(feature_class)
for row in cursor:
  label = ""
  difference = row.getValue('Difference')
  if difference == 0:
    label += "Label is 0"
  elif difference > 0.30:
    // ...
  row.setValue("Label", label)
  cursor.updateRow(row)
```